# longest common substring k gap

Tags: c++, algorithm, computer-science, lcs

Longest Common String with one Gap allowed

So I want to find out the longest common string among the two strings for eg AABA and AAGA

such that it can ignore one char that is B and G to give longest common substring as AAA

I tried the logic using recursion but couldn't reach to conclusion

My code:

```
int lcs(int i, int j, int count) 

{ 

    

    if (i == 0 || j == 0) 

        return count; 

        

    if (X\[i-1\] == Y\[j-1\]) { 

        count = lcs(i - 1, j - 1, count + 1); 

        

    } 

    

  if (X\[i-2\] == Y\[j-2\])

    count = lcs(i -2, j -2, count + 1);

    



&#x200B;

        count = max(count, max(lcs( i, j - 1, 0), lcs( i - 1, j, 0))); 

    return count; 

}
```

where i and j are size of these two strings and count is the length of largest common string.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495298/how-can-we-calculate-longest-common-substring-with-one-atmost-one-skip)?

Comment: sorry mate kinda new here . would be kind if u could help me with this question

Comment: I guess that you can use dynamic programming and add `bool` flag into the state space. That is, in addition to `i` and `j` you also have `bool f`. `f` indicates whether or not you have one mismatch so far. If you do, you have standard LCS recurrence relation, if you don't, you can ignore last characters match condition and set `f = true`. You start with `f = false`.